# system.js fail to properly display error messages from babel

Tags: babeljs, systemjs, jspm

When I setup a very simple project with `jspm` using `system.js` and `babel`, it seems that the error messages are not correctly displayed.

I did the following :

```
npm init; press enter a bunch of times
jspm init; press enter a bunch of times
```

And added two files :

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="jspm_packages/system.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('test 1');
    System.import('main');
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

`main.js`

```
console.log('test2);
//                ^ I voluntarily forgot the ' to show the error;
```

According to [this talk](https://youtu.be/NpMnRifyGyw?t=12m6s), and previous experiences with babel, I should see some very nice syntax error messages, like this one : [image: nice error message]

But instead, I got this, which is completely cryptic, and doesn't help me a bit :
[image: not nice error message]

Because of the error line saying `system.js:1:0`, I believe the error happens in system.js, and it fails before calling babel.
Moreover, I noticed `es6-module-loader` isn't loaded. I thought it was used in `system.js`.

I don't see what I am missing here.

Comment: Same problem I am facing here, let me know if you solved it.

Comment: @NasifMd.Tanjim, it was a while back, and finally moved to webpack, instead of jspm. But if I remember correctly, switching to Chrome gave me better error messages. Still not satisfying.